# facebook connect on iPhone - making calls is giving error 102 "Session key invalid or no longer valid", yet the stream dialogs still work

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

Anyone see this?
I've a situation whereby sometimes, [session resume] returns YES.  I make a FBRequest.call, and the error delegate gets called.
The error has 102 "Session key invalid or no longer valid".
However, if within the same session I call up any FBDialogs (e.gr. to publish to a stream), these all work fine.  I don't see why they are not suffering the same error.

Any ideas?

Yes.  I know there's a forum for facebook connect, but its taking an age to get my password sent to me. (Yes...there's an irony there - why didn't they just use facebook connect for their forums...ho hum).

Comment: This doesn't answer your main question, but [session resume] only does a local check to make sure you have a saved session key and that its expiration date hasn't passed. It doesn't do any actual validation with Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)resume {
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  FBUID uid = [[defaults objectForKey:@"FBUserId"] longLongValue];
  if (uid) {
    NSDate* expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBSessionExpires"];
    if (!expirationDate || [expirationDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
      _uid = uid;
      _sessionKey = [[defaults stringForKey:@"FBSessionKey"] copy];
      _sessionSecret = [[defaults stringForKey:@"FBSessionSecret"] copy];
      _expirationDate = [expirationDate retain];

      for (id<FBSessionDelegate> delegate in _delegates) {
        [delegate session:self didLogin:_uid];
      }
      return YES;
    }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Here is the code of that method, I don't think that the code is trying to make the connection with facebook to test, they just get the expiration date. I think that sometimes, when you logout of facebook, the session does not expire but on server side, they delete your session